# Change style of hover and tooltip in chartjs or ng2-charts

Tags: chart.js, ng2-charts

is there any way to change style of hover as well as the tooltip with chartjs or ng2-charts? I want to hide the hover points and only display them whenever I hover on them along with the indicator as the line. Here is the exact chart model I want to build:

https://interactive-bitcoin-price-chart-foxkmkynmg.now.sh/

Thank you in advance for your tips.

EDIT: I followed instructions of GRUNT to apply this chart option into my Angular app, the full chart is shown with tooltip whenever I hover, but the line-trace indicator is not. Here are my codes:

plugin-hoverline.ts:

```
export class PluginHoverline {
   posX: null;
   isMouseOut:boolean = false;

   drawLine(chart, posX) {
      const ctx = chart.ctx,
         x_axis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'],
         y_axis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'],
         x = posX,
         topY = y_axis.top,
         bottomY = y_axis.bottom;
      if (posX < x_axis.left || posX > x_axis.right) return;
      // draw line
      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(x, topY);
      ctx.lineTo(x, bottomY);
      ctx.lineWidth = chart.options.lineOnHover.lineWidth;
      ctx.strokeStyle = chart.options.lineOnHover.lineColor;
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.restore();
   };

   beforeInit(chart) {
      chart.options.events.push('mouseover');
   };

   afterEvent(chart, event) {
      if (!chart.options.lineOnHover || !chart.options.lineOnHover.enabled) return;
      if (event.type !== 'mousemove' && event.type !== 'mouseover') {
         if (event.type === 'mouseout') this.isMouseOut = true;
         chart.clear();
         chart.draw();
         return;
      }
      this.posX = event.x;
      this.isMouseOut = false;
      chart.clear();
      chart.draw();
      this.drawLine(chart, this.posX);

      var metaData = chart.getDatasetMeta(0).data,
         radius = chart.data.datasets[0].pointHoverRadius,
         posX = metaData.map(e => e._model.x);
      posX.forEach(function(pos, posIndex) {
         if (this.posX < pos + radius && this.posX > pos - radius) {
            chart.updateHoverStyle([metaData[posIndex]], null, true);
            chart.tooltip._active = [metaData[posIndex]];
         } else chart.updateHoverStyle([metaData[posIndex]], null, false);
      }.bind(this));
      chart.tooltip.update();
   };

   afterDatasetsDraw(chart, ease) {
      if (!this.posX) return;
      if (!this.isMouseOut) this.drawLine(chart, this.posX);
   };
}
```

banner.component.ts: (chart component)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HistoricalBpiService } from '../../services/historical-bpi.service';
import { PluginHoverline } from './plugin-hoverline';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-banner',
  templateUrl: './banner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./banner.component.scss']
})
export class BannerComponent implements OnInit {

  private dataUrl: string = 'historical/close.json';

  constructor(
    private historicalBpiService:HistoricalBpiService
  ) {}

  // lineChart
  public lineChartData:any = [
    { data:[], label: 'Bitcoin price' }
  ];

  public lineChartLabels:Array<any> = [];

  public lineChartOptions:any = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    layout: {
      padding: 0
    },
    lineOnHover: {
     enabled: true,
     lineColor: '#bbb',
     lineWidth: 1
   },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: false,
          labelString: 'USD'
        },
        ticks: {
          display: false
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: true,
          tickMarkLength: 0
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          display: false
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
          tickMarkLength: 0
        }
      }]
    },
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 3
      },
      line: {
        tension: 0.4, // 0 disables bezier curves
      }
    },
    hover: {
      mode: 'nearest',
      intersect: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'nearest',
      intersect: false,
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(95,22,21)',
      callbacks: {
        label: function (tooltipItems, data) {
          return data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label + ' : ' + '$' + tooltipItems.yLabel.toLocaleString();
        },
        labelColor: function(tooltipItem, chart) {
          var dataset = chart.config.data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
          return {
            backgroundColor : dataset.backgroundColor
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
  public lineChartColors:Array<any> = [
    {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(199,32,48,0.8',
      borderColor: 'rgb(95,22,21);',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(218,208,163,0.8)',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(218,208,163,0.8)',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(218,208,163)',
      pointHoverRadius: 6,
      steppedLine: false

    }
  ];
  public lineChartLegend:boolean = false;
  public lineChartType:string = 'line';


  // events
  public chartClicked(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }

  public chartHovered(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.historicalBpiService.getBpiData(this.dataUrl)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          //this.lineChartData = Object.keys(res.bpi).map(function (key) { return res.bpi[key];});
          this.lineChartData[0].data = Object.values(res.bpi);
          this.lineChartLabels = Object.keys(res.bpi);
          //console.log(this.lineChartData,this.lineChartLabels);
        }
      )
  }
}
```

template:

```
<div class="chart">
      <canvas baseChart height="360px"
        [datasets]="lineChartData"
        [labels]="lineChartLabels"
        [options]="lineChartOptions"
        [colors]="lineChartColors"
        [legend]="lineChartLegend"
        [chartType]="lineChartType"
        (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
        (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no built-in functionality for this yet. However you can use [**this**](https://istack.000webhostapp.com/chartjs-plugin-hoverline.js) chart plugin *(once created for my own purpose)* to achieve your goal.

To utilize the plugin, set the following option in your chart­*'s* options config :

```
lineOnHover: {
   enabled: true,
   lineColor: '#bbb',
   lineWidth: 1
}
```

also, make sure to set the following properties for your dataset :

```
pointRadius: 0,
pointHoverRadius: 5,
pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'white'
```

see - [**live demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/2j9cqkpo/)

Comment: Alright, thank you for you information. For now this solution with plugin is fine. Do you have other solutions without using external plugin? I searched for similar plugin on npm but not found.

Comment: No! As I said there's no native solution for this atm. You must use a plugin and there's no harm using plugins, as they're used to extend charts functionality, and you can even create your own plugin if you want any custom features. That being said, this is a custom made plugin and can't be found on npm *(as I haven't released it)*

Comment: Hi, but how to register this plugin and use it in my chart component in my Angular cli app?

Comment: First, download the plugin script locally and change its file ext to `.ts`. Then place it inside your chart component folder and then import it (`import './chartjs-plugin-hoverline';`) in your chart.component.ts file.

Comment: Hello, I edited my question including my codes. Can you take a look please? Thank you

Comment: I did as you said, but somehow still not work :(. I even moved the chart options to ngOnInit as the demo, but the ViewChild affects this hoverline? I haven't tried this input before.

Comment: ah.. that's just a demo and there are some redundant codes that you won't need to worry about..

Comment: Here it is, thank you for you help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46239507/chartjs-ng2-charts-line-on-hover-does-not-work

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to build on top of [GRUNT's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46171229/change-style-of-hover-and-tooltip-in-chartjs-or-ng2-charts#answer-46179051) to be able to display if its a multiline graph:

---

Just change the following (in the code snippet he provide [here](https://istack.000webhostapp.com/chartjs-plugin-hoverline.js)):

```
posX.forEach(function(pos, posIndex) {
  if (this.posX < pos + radius && this.posX > pos - radius) {
    chart.updateHoverStyle([metaData[posIndex]], null, true);
    chart.tooltip._active = [metaData[posIndex]];
  } else chart.updateHoverStyle([metaData[posIndex]], null, false);
}.bind(this));
```

to:

```
posX.forEach(function(pos, posIndex) {
  var metaDatum = []
  if (this.posX < pos + radius && this.posX > pos - radius) {
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset, ind) => {
      metaDatum.push(chart.getDatasetMeta(ind).data[posIndex]);
    })

    chart.updateHoverStyle(metaDatum, null, true);
    chart.tooltip._active = metaDatum;
  } else {
    metaDatum.push(metaData[posIndex]);
    chart.updateHoverStyle(metaDatum, null, false);
  }
}.bind(this));
```