# Chartjs / ng2-charts line on hover does not work

Tags: chart.js, ng2-charts

I'm trying to optimize my chart using ng2-charts on Angular cli app. In general, everything works just fine, the only thing does not is the line on hover to track the data point. This is the ideal chart model I try to make and I also tried to follow its code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/line-chart?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

However, when I hover on my chart, only the tooltip is shown.

Here are my codes:

plugin-hoverline.ts: (copy & paste from the link below, credit by @GRUNT)

https://istack.000webhostapp.com/chartjs-plugin-hoverline.js

banner.component.ts: (chart component)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HistoricalBpiService } from '../../services/historical-bpi.service';
import './plugin-hoverline';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-banner',
  templateUrl: './banner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./banner.component.scss']
})
export class BannerComponent implements OnInit {

  currentDate:string = new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,'-');

  private dataUrl: string = 'historical/close.json?start=2013-09-01&end=' + this.currentDate;

  constructor(    
    private historicalBpiService:HistoricalBpiService
  ) {}

  // lineChart

  public lineChartData:any = [
    { data:[], label: 'BTC' }
  ];

  public lineChartLabels:Array<any> = [];

  public lineChartOptions:any = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    layout: {
      padding: 0
    },
    lineOnHover: {
     enabled: true,
     lineColor: '#bbb',
     lineWidth: 1
   },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        display: false,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: false,
          labelString: 'USD'
        },
        ticks: {
          //min: 0,
          //max: 5000,
          stepSize: 500,
          display: false,
          mirror: true,
          labelOffset: 7,
          padding: -10,
          callback: function(value, index, values) {
            return '$' + value;
          }
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: true,
          tickMarkLength: 0
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          display: false,
          mirror: true
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false,
          tickMarkLength: 0
        }
      }]
    },
    elements: {
      point: {
        radius: 0
      },
      line: {
        tension: 0, // 0 disables bezier curves
      }
    },
    hover: {
      mode: 'nearest',
      intersect: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'nearest',
      intersect: false,
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(95,22,21)',
      callbacks: {
        title: function (tooltipItems, data) {
          return (tooltipItems[0] || {})['xLabel'];
        },
        label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
          return '$ ' + tooltipItem.yLabel.toLocaleString();
        },
        labelColor: function(tooltipItem, chart) {
          let dataset = chart.config.data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
          return {
            backgroundColor : dataset.backgroundColor
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };
  public lineChartColors:Array<any> = [
    {
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(199,32,48,0.9',
      borderColor: 'rgb(95,22,21);',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(218,208,163,0.9)',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(218,208,163,0.9)',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(218,208,163)',
      pointHoverRadius: 5,
      steppedLine: false

    }
  ];
  public lineChartLegend:boolean = false;
  public lineChartType:string = 'line';


  // events
  public chartClicked(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }

  public chartHovered(e:any):void {
    console.log(e);
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.historicalBpiService.getBpiData(this.dataUrl)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          //this.lineChartData = Object.keys(res.bpi).map(function (key) { return res.bpi[key];});
          this.lineChartData[0].data = Object.values(res.bpi);
          this.lineChartLabels = Object.keys(res.bpi);
          //console.log(this.lineChartData,this.lineChartLabels);
        }
      )
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="chart">
      <canvas baseChart height="360px"
        [datasets]="lineChartData"
        [labels]="lineChartLabels"
        [options]="lineChartOptions"
        [colors]="lineChartColors"
        [legend]="lineChartLegend"
        [chartType]="lineChartType"
        (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
        (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY using the following code :

**chart component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HistoricalBpiService } from '../../services/historical-bpi.service';
import './plugin-hoverline';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-banner',
   templateUrl: './banner.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./banner.component.scss']
})
export class BannerComponent implements OnInit {

   currentDate: string = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '-');

   private dataUrl: string = 'historical/close.json?start=2013-09-01&end=' + this.currentDate;

   constructor(
      private historicalBpiService: HistoricalBpiService
   ) { }

   // lineChart

   public lineChartData: any = [
      { data: [], label: 'BTC', pointHoverRadius: 5, steppedLine: false }
   ];

   public lineChartLabels: Array<any> = [];

   public lineChartOptions: any = {
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
      layout: {
         padding: 0
      },
      lineOnHover: {
         enabled: true,
         lineColor: '#bbb',
         lineWidth: 1
      },
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            display: false,
            scaleLabel: {
               display: false,
               labelString: 'USD'
            },
            ticks: {
               //min: 0,
               //max: 5000,
               stepSize: 500,
               display: false,
               mirror: true,
               labelOffset: 7,
               padding: -10,
               callback: function (value, index, values) {
                  return '$' + value;
               }
            },
            gridLines: {
               display: true,
               tickMarkLength: 0
            }
         }],
         xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               display: false,
               mirror: true
            },
            gridLines: {
               display: false,
               tickMarkLength: 0
            }
         }]
      },
      elements: {
         point: {
            radius: 0
         },
         line: {
            tension: 0, // 0 disables bezier curves
         }
      },
      hover: {
         mode: 'nearest',
         intersect: true
      },
      tooltips: {
         mode: 'nearest',
         intersect: true,
         backgroundColor: 'rgb(95,22,21)',
         callbacks: {
            title: function (tooltipItems, data) {
               return (tooltipItems[0] || {})['xLabel'];
            },
            label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
               return '$ ' + tooltipItem.yLabel.toLocaleString();
            },
            labelColor: function (tooltipItem, chart) {
               let dataset = chart.config.data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
               return {
                  backgroundColor: dataset.backgroundColor
               }
            }
         }
      }
   };
   public lineChartColors: Array<any> = [
      {
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(199,32,48,0.9',
         borderColor: 'rgb(95,22,21);',
         pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(218,208,163,0.9)',
         pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(218,208,163,0.9)',
         pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(218,208,163)'

      }
   ];
   public lineChartLegend: boolean = false;
   public lineChartType: string = 'line';


   // events
   public chartClicked(e: any): void {
      console.log(e);
   }

   public chartHovered(e: any): void {
      console.log(e);
   }

   ngOnInit() {
      this.historicalBpiService.getBpiData(this.dataUrl)
         .subscribe(
         res => {
            //this.lineChartData = Object.keys(res.bpi).map(function (key) { return res.bpi[key];});
            this.lineChartData[0].data = Object.values(res.bpi);
            this.lineChartLabels = Object.keys(res.bpi);
            //console.log(this.lineChartData,this.lineChartLabels);
         }
         )
   }
}
```

You should set the **`pointHoverRadius`** property inside `lineChartData` array instead of `lineChartColors`, also set the **`intersect`** property to **`true`** for both `hover` and `tooltips`

Comment: oh after refreshing several times, a bug was shown and my app was not able to run and I just noticed that your live demo also shows the same bug: plugin-hoverline.ts (1,1): Cannot find name 'Chart'.

Comment: hm.. add `declare const Chart: any;` at the top of plugin script

Comment: woohoo, it worked finally, I can't thank you enough for your help <3

Comment: Great !! Cheers !!

Comment: oh hi, my chart has much data point, so when I hover on any data point, the chart always shows two hover points together. How can I show only one data point on every hover even though much data? Here is the example, even data for 1 year or all data the chart always only 1 data point when hover: https://www.coindesk.com/price/

Comment: but when radius is 1, the data points are too small that it's hard to notice them. Here is my chart with pointHoverRadius: 5 and elements.point.radius: 0 (https://c1.staticflickr.com/5/4337/37129200496_91cb71e82e_b.jpg)

Comment: where have you changed the `radius`? I said to change it in plugin script. this > `radius = chart.data.datasets[0].pointHoverRadius,` to this > `radius = 1,`

Comment: oh yes, I was foolish, it worked when I changed radius to 2.5, thank you so much !!!